# Difference between importing file from the same directory and from node_modules

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why is typescript compiler fine with importing from JS file from local directory, but complains about importing from `node_modules`?

Code:

```
import { t2 } from "./t1.js"
t2.hello();

import { mat4 } from "./node_modules/gl-matrix/esm/index.js";
mat4.create();
```

Error:

```
main.ts:4:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module './node_modules/gl-matrix/esm/index.js'. '/.../node_modules/gl-matrix/esm/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

4 import { mat4 } from "./node_modules/gl-matrix/esm/index.js";
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I comment the last two lines it compiles fine.

Repro steps.

```
npm install --save-dev typescript gl-matrix
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "outDir": "./obj",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
}
```

`t1.js` (mimics content of `index.js` from gl-matrix):

```
import * as t2 from "./t2.js"
export { t2 };
```

`t2.js` (mimics content of `mat4.js` from gl-matrix):

```
export function hello() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: Your `import`s should never contain `"./node_modules"`; `import { mat4 } from "gl-matrix";` should be enough.

Comment: @AKX, does typescript compiler treat "node_modules" in some special way? I tried copying it to other location and it seems to work. Also, `from "gl-matrix"` seem to only work when `moduleResolution` (and `module`) is set to `NodeNext`. I want the output to be ES modules.

Comment: Where will you be using the output?

Comment: @AKX, ultimately in a browser and I want to bundle it into a single file (with rollup, I suppose). But I am really interested in understanding what's going on here instead of just making it work.

Comment: Right, well, the bundler will deal with module resolution when it stuffs things into your bundle. Anyway, let me write an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `import` statement should never, ever contain the word `node_modules`; that directory name is an implementation detail. (In a browser, you might have an [import map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type/importmap), for instance. Or, in a Node environment, you could import the built-in file-system module as `'node:fs'`.)

The message you're getting,

> Could not find a declaration file for module './node_modules/gl-matrix/esm/index.js'. [It] implicitly has an 'any' type.

is not exactly a fatal error, it's Typescript telling you it doesn't have types for that module, and it rightly so doesn't, because you're side-stepping the entire `package.json` to tell you you just want some stuff from [this file](https://unpkg.com/gl-matrix@3.4.3/esm/index.js).

If you were to do `import {mat4} from "gl-matrix";` (as you should), the compiler will do module resolution, figure out which module format to use (ESM or CJS) and it will find [the types.d.ts file](https://unpkg.com/gl-matrix@3.4.3/types.d.ts/package.json) and know where to find the type definitions for each version.

If you copy the file to your local source tree and import it, things change since TypeScript will then infer types from it like it would for any of your own code (and happily, the ESM modules for `gl-matrix` [have](https://unpkg.com/gl-matrix@3.4.3/esm/vec4.js) JSDoc comments,  which TSC can parse and use).

Comment: It seems I have been confused by the `module` setting comment generated by `tsc --init`: "Specify what module code is generated". Apparently, it does much more than just specify the output module kind and in my case it has to be set to Node16/NodeNext.